# Idiomatic way to include a null character / byte in a string in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I was messing around with the OCaml Unix module to see if it would reject strings containing certain bytes that might have surprising effects in the context of the given system call and throw an exception. E.g. a null byte in the `prog` argument to `Unix.create_process`, or a newline in one of the strings in the `env : string array` argument.

I tried a few ways to include a null byte in my string, such as `"/bin/ls\0"` (which is an illegal escape sequence in a string literal) and `"/bin/ls" ^ string_of_char '\0'` (which is an illegal sequence in a character literal). Finally, I cast zero to a string, and then made a string of length 1 containing the null character and then concatenated it with my string.

```
module U = Unix;;

let string_of_char ch : string = String.make 1 ch

let sketchy_string = "/bin/ls" ^ string_of_char (char_of_int 0)

let _ = U.create_process sketchy_string [|"ls"|] U.stdin U.stdout U.stderr
```

What's the right way to add a null byte to an ocaml string?

Comment: BTW, how did the Unix module handle all those null bytes?

Comment: the `create_process` function in the Unix module ignores characters after the first null byte, so it looks like it's converting the ocaml string to a null-terminated string without checking its contents. I'll have to check how it's implemented.

Comment: strings in OCaml are always terminated, so there is no need to append an extra null character. https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html#string-values

Comment: @ivg, the goal was to determine if `Unix.create_process` and other functions like it would throw an exception if a null byte was present in the any of the strings it takes as arguments. The documentation for the Unix module doesn't mention anything about prohibiting null bytes or sanity-checking input. I wanted to see if the function was essentially null-terminating the string and handing it into the system call(s) verbatim.

Comment: it doesn't since it is null-terminated by design. But if you've put a null in the middle, then it will not detect it and cut off the string, e.g., `"rm -rf /\x00/tmp/folder"` will remove the root filesystem, instead of the `/tmp/folder` (I didn't try the code :)) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the generic "hexadecimal code" escape sequence to write the null byte (or any other byte you want):

```
let null_byte = '\x00';;
let sketchy_string = "/bin/ls\x00";;
```

For further reference, see the section of the Ocaml manual covering escape sequences: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#escape-sequence